# Serilog on .Net 6 web API

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, serilog

I am doing my first project on .Net 6, a web API. The wish is to have Serilog, to save both log and later to GreyLog.
I am facing some issues, as I am new to .Net 6

When I add it to the program.cs, as

```
string logFileName = "scp_.log"; // mapping?
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
   .WriteTo.File(
       path: logFileName,
       retainedFileCountLimit: 7,
       shared: true,
       rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
       rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
       fileSizeLimitBytes: 123456,
       flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
     .CreateLogger();
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);
```

Then it applies to the system only. I want a log for myself, and I can create that in the controller.
I was hoping to creating it once and it would be in all my controllers.

When creating in program.cs, it does not apply to controllers or anything.
Is there a simple way to have one for everything?

How do I map the path as I used to in .Net Framework?
Like this

```
     string logFileName = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/old_project_.log");
```

I can use this:

```
public AdminController(ILogger<AdminController> logger, IWebHostEnvironment host)
{
   string logfile = Path.Combine(host.ContentRootPath, "scp_.log");
```

by adding the `IWebHostEnviroment` manually. This is the same as simply using "scp_.log".
Is this the right way? I used to get log files in my bin\debug folder or api folder on the server

I do not have a server yet as I just started creating this project

Can I use the present logger (`ILogger<AdminController>`) in the system to log files and later also to Greylog?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I think you're over thinking this. I've added serilog to a few different projects and I've just used instructions from the serilog repos. Look at a few different repos to see what fits:

- [serilog-aspnetcore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore)
- [serilog-extensions-logging](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging)
- [serilog-extensions-hosting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting)

It's really pretty basic to get serilog setup. Which is one reason it's so popular. The documentation is pretty good in how to get things setup. It may not be exactly what you need, but it'll give you the framework to get things setup.